# Group together array elements

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array in PHP:-

```
$arr = ["BX_NAME0","BX_NAME1","BX_NAME2","BX_categoryName0","BX_categoryName1","BX_categoryName2","BHA_categories0","BHA_categories1","BHA_categories2"]
```

Here I want to group together elements based on same ending integer together in json like

```
$post_data = array(
      '0' => array(
        'BX_NAME0' => $item_type,
        'BX_categoryName0' => $string_key,
        'BHA_categories0' => $string_value
      ),
      '1' => array(
        'BX_NAME1' => $item_type,
        'BX_categoryName1' => $string_key,
        'BHA_categories1' => $string_value
      ),
);
```

I have Used:- `filter_var($key , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

to get the integer part of the array elements but don't known how to group them further.

Comment: https://eval.in/715548

Comment: @Anant it works like charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You can do it like below using preg_match():-***

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($arr as $ar){
   preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ar, $matches); //get the number from string
   $new_array[$matches[0][0]][$ar] = '';

}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/715548

Comment: @smarttechy   glad to help you.Cheers:):)

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:-

```
$arr = array("BX_NAME0","BX_NAME1","BX_NAME2","BX_categoryName0","BX_categoryName1","BX_categoryName2","BHA_categories0","BHA_categories1","BHA_categories2");

$post_data = array();

foreach($arr as $value) {
    $key = filter_var($value , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if(isset($post_data[$key]) && !is_array($post_data[$key])) {
         $post_data[$key] = array();
    }
    $post_data[$key][] = $value;
}

print_r($post_data);
```

Tested and works
However, I suggest you use substr() to get the last character of the array item, for performance and stuff..

Comment: @Anant his solution works and he answered firstly then the rest of the people here.

Comment: Changed it to what OP wants

Answer (score 2):

**By using `filter_var()`  method**

```
$arr = ["BX_NAME0","BX_NAME1","BX_NAME2","BX_categoryName0","BX_categoryName1","BX_categoryName2","BHA_categories0","BHA_categories1","BHA_categories2"];
    foreach($arr as $a){
        $int = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $newarr[$int][$a] = '';
    }
    print_r($newarr);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/715581

Comment: just edited the answer. filter_var() , works also. Please check this https://eval.in/715581 , if its not as expected, then i'll remove my answer.